# Peek into local network messages on set ports (using C#RMI)

Tags: c#, encryption, windows-services, rmi, sendmessage

I have a question about C# message sending. I am using RMI in C# which is working on local network on a set port (windows service and windows form communication). I do not encrypt the messages between them as I think the messages could not be really caught/modified via third party.

Is that true, or should I use encryption? There are not any really sensitive data, but just in case and of course I do not want to leave it vulnerable.

I hope my question kind of makes sense, if not do not hesitate to ask. Please share your experience/preference.

Answer (score 0):

Are you going across the internet? Then probably

Are you on an internal network, behind a firewall, with trusty employees, then its probably not worth the hassle.

HTTP is not encrypted, and neither is about 80% of SMTP communication.

It all depends how sensitive your not so sensitive data is.